# Why is myArrayList.size(); producing incorrect/gigantic numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, binary

Basically, I'm trying to write a program that converts a number from base 2 to base 10. What I tried doing was translating the process listed on this website under the "Doubling method" into a for loop, but for some reason the numbers I'm getting are way to big.

The basic formula is (2 * previousTotal) + (currentDigit of the ArrayList that holds the user's inputted binary number) = previousTotal.

So for 1011001 in binary, the math would be:

- (0 x 2) + 1 = 1
- (1 x 2) + 0 = 2
- (2 x 2) + 1 = 5
- (5 x 2) + 1 = 11
- (11x 2) + 0 = 22
- (22 x 2) + 0 = 44
- (44 x 2) + 1 = 89

The console however, prints out 6185 as the result. I'm thinking it might have something to do with me using an ArrayList of characters, but the charWhole.size() returns 7, which is how many digits are in the user's binary number. As soon as I do charsWhole.get(w); however, I start getting big numbers such as 49. I'd really appreciate some help!

I wrote out this loop, and according to some print statements that I placed throughout the code and my variable addThis seems to be where the problem is. The console prints out a final total of 6185, when 1011001 in base 10 is actually 89.

```
public static void backto2(){
    System.out.println("What base are you coming from?");
    Scanner backToB10 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bringMeBack = backToB10.nextInt();

    //whole
    System.out.println("Please enter the whole number part of your number.");
    Scanner eachDigit = new Scanner(System.in);
    String theirNumber = eachDigit.nextLine();

    String str = theirNumber;
    ArrayList<Character> charsWhole = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char testt : str.toCharArray()) {
      charsWhole.add(testt);
    }



    System.out.println(theirNumber); // User's number
    System.out.println(charsWhole); // User's number separated into elements of an ArrayList
    System.out.println(charsWhole.size()); // Gets size of arrayList, comes out as 7 which seems fine.

    int previousTotal = 0, addThis = 0, q =0;
    for( int w = 0; w < charsWhole.size(); w ++) {
        addThis = charsWhole.get(w); //current digit of arraylist PROBLEM           
        q = previousTotal *2;
        previousTotal = q + addThis; // previous total gets updated
        System.out.println(q);
        System.out.println(addThis);

        System.out.println(q + " and " + addThis + "equals " + previousTotal);


    }

    System.out.println(previousTotal);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are attempting to add a character to an integer.  The implicit conversion uses the ASCII value of the character, so that '1' gets converted to 49, not 1, because 49 is the code for the character '1'.  Subtract '0' to get the actual integer value.

```
addThis = charsWhole.get(w) - '0';
```

This works because the digits 0-9 are represented in ASCII as the codes 48-57, so in effect you will, for '1', subtract 49 - 48 to get 1.

You'll still have to handle cases when the character is outside the range of allowable characters.

**EDIT**

Java uses Unicode, but for the purposes of the codes for the digits 0-9, the codes are the same (48 thru 57, or 0x30 thru 0x39) in both ASCII and Unicode.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much.. I would have never known it was using the ASCII value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the chars rather than the number value they represent. In the line

```
addThis = charsWhole.get(w);
```

the value of `addThis` is the ascii value of the character. For '0', this is 48. Use this instead:

```
addThis = Integer.parseInt(charsWhole.get(w));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion to solve the same problem:

```
addThis = charsWhole.getNumericValue(w);
```

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_getnumericvalue.htm) for more information.